# Angular function continuously called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I have an ng-if that checks user access for certain links in my Angular app:

`<li ng-if="hasAccess('admin')"><a href="#/admin">admin</a></li>`

In my Angular app `.run`, I've added a rootscope function:

```
    $rootScope.hasAccess = function (type) {
        if ($rootScope.me && $rootScope.me.groups) {
            return $rootScope.me.groups.filter(function (group) {
                return group.id === type;
            }).length > 0;
        } else {
            console.log(type + ' cannot be verified. $rootScope.me has not been set');
        }
    };
```

Sometimes this function is infinitely called (I'm assuming through the digest cycles), but I am not sure why.

Comment: ng-if="getAccess('admin')" or ng-if="hasAccess('admin')"?

Comment: @Growler i would recommend to go with hitmands solution, every time the page loads, it will trigger the method. Have the method on the init call of your controller and access it as a boolean in ng-if

Comment: @ThillaiNarayanan what about one time binding? `<div ng-if="::hasAdminAccess">He is Admin</div>`

Comment: @NoSkill that could be a useful answer on the dupe target

Answer (score 2):

That function is **continuously called** because the *ngIf* directive is evaluated on each **Digest Cycle**...

If you want to exec that function just once try this:

```js
$rootScope.hasAccess = function (type) {
  if ($rootScope.me && $rootScope.me.groups) {
    return $rootScope.me.groups.filter(function (group) {
      return group.id === type;
    }).length > 0;
  } else {
    console.log(type + ' cannot be verified. $rootScope.me has not been set');
  }
};
$rootScope.hasAdminAccess = $rootScope.hasAccess('admin');
```

```html
<div ng-if="hasAdminAccess">He is Admin</div>
```

Comment: there is native angular solution - one time binding: `<div ng-if="::hasAdminAccess">He is Admin</div>`